# What is the legal status of patent US20110223816 US 13/600,467

Tags: legal-status

I would like to know the legal status of this patent:

> US20110223816
>   Application number    US 13/600,467

Where can I find the status or does anybody know its status by chance?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:- Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action

How to find:-

1. Go to http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair
2. enter the publication number:- 20110223816
3. check status of child applications which will have status for 13/600,467 you can also go for hyperlink at said number which will lead you to patent application landing page with status.

follow the following steps

[image]